How can I have each `using` of a base struct be a different type?
I have a tuple of elements that I want to access using std::get with the type name:
template<typename... Params>
struct SomeType
{
    std::tuple<Params...> params;
};

using TypeOne = SomeType<std::string, int, double>;
using TypeTwo = SomeType<std::string, std::string, int>;
using TypeThree = SomeType<std::string, int, double>;

...

std::tuple<TypeOne, TypeTwo, TypeThree> tuple;

//Works via index, but I want to use the type
auto first = std::get<0>(tuple);
auto second = std::get<1>(tuple);
auto third = std::get<2>(tuple);

//Doesn't work here since TypeOne and TypeThree are the same
auto onth = std::get<TypeOne>(tuple);
auto twoth = std::get<TypeTwo>(tuple);
auto threeth = std::get<TypeThree>(tuple);

My current resolution is to have the first parameter be a lambda type:
template<typename ID, typename... Params>
struct SomeTypeWithId
{
    SomeTypeWithId(Params... _params)
        : params(std::make_tuple(_params...))
    {}

    std::tuple<Params...> params;
};

using TypeOneWithID = SomeTypeWithId<decltype([](){}), std::string, int, double>;
using TypeTwoWithID = SomeTypeWithId<decltype([](){}), std::string, std::string, int>;
using TypeThreeWithID = SomeTypeWithId<decltype([](){}), std::string, int, double>;

std::tuple<TypeOneWithID, TypeTwoWithID, TypeThreeWithID> tuple;

//Works since they're all different types now
auto onth = std::get<TypeOneWithID>(tuple);
auto twoth = std::get<TypeTwoWithID>(tuple);
auto threeth = std::get<TypeThreeWithID>(tuple);

But the syntax here is annoying as I do not want to have to always have to put decltype([](){}) in all my using declaratives. I thought I could get away with something like this:
template<typename ID, typename... Params>
struct SomeTypeWithId;

template<typename... Params>
struct SomeTypeWithId<decltype([](){}), Params...>
{
    SomeTypeWithId(Params... _params)
        : params(std::make_tuple(_params...))
    {}

    std::tuple<Params...> params;
};

But it doesn't work. How can I achieve this? My issue is that the index of the elements will likely change (across various tuples), but their names will not.
Compile Explorer Playground

You can use CRTP: struct TypeOneWithID: SomeTypeWithId<TypeOneWithID, std::string, int, double> {};

@n.m.couldbeanAI That's interesting. I was hoping to stick to the using syntax as its intuitive and widespread, but this works too..

You could just define types instead of making typedefs:
template <class... Params>
struct SomeType {
    std::tuple<Params...> params;
};

struct TypeOneWithID : SomeType<std::string, int, double> {};
struct TypeTwoWithID : SomeType<std::string, std::string, int> {};
struct TypeThreeWithID : SomeType<std::string, int, double> {};


Sorry, I have been gone for a little bit (busy with some work stuff). This is a simple and elegant solution.

1. Using type wrappers
If you want to create two types that share the same base type but are treated as different types, you can use type wrappers.
For example, you can create distinct structs for each type you might use:
struct TypeOne
{
    SomeType<std::string, int, double> value;
};

struct TypeThree
{
    SomeType<std::string, int, double> value;
};

Alternatively, you can create structs derived directly from SomeTypeWithId:
struct TypeOneWithId : SomeTypeWithId<TypeOneWithID, std::string, int, double>
{
};

struct TypeThreeWithId : SomeTypeWithId<TypeThreeWithID, std::string, int, double>
{
};

2. Using a counter
To continue using the using alias, you can slightly modify the base struct so that it accepts an int as its ID:
template<int ID, typename... Params>
struct SomeTypeWithId
{  /* ... */  };

Then you can use the __COUNTER__ preprocessor directive, which, while non-standard, is supported by many compilers (such as GCC, Clang, etc.). It generates unique value every time it is found by the preprocessor.
using TypeOneWithID = SomeTypeWithId<__COUNTER__, std::string, int, double>;
using TypeThreeWithID = SomeTypeWithId<__COUNTER__, std::string, int, double>;

If you want your code to be compliant with the standard, you can also make a compile-time counter yourself: See Does C++ support compile-time counters?

Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, the first one doesn't really work for me as its too much writing (I have about 70 of these!) and the second one is basically what I am doing currently.
